# Making two different rows in bootstrap have same-height elements

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, whitespace

I asked a similar question that I'll go delete because this one specifically focuses on my true issue: making them the same height.

I have two different rows in bootstrap, one with 3 divs (images) and one with 4 divs (also images). The images are the exact same shape and aspect ratio (rectangular), but I want them to stay the same size. Basically, I want the second row of elements to move closer (maybe by overlapping rows) so that all the elements are the same size as the top row.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            Caption
                            <div class="caption-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-3x">Hello</i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/BLM.png" class="triUp img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
<!-- +3x in row. . . .--> </div>

<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 portfolio-item dontwantpadding">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal4" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/ALS.jpg" class="triUp img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
<!-- +3x in row. . . .--> </div>
```

The images themselves are squares, but they are masked in triangles. I included a picture below.

[image: I have since set the padding and margins to zero, but problem persists]

Comment: This is kind of weird issue. What exactly is your problem? Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: @robjez thanks for responding, I tried to set up a JS fiddle, but there's just too much intertwined css to make it feasible there. BUT I'm hosting what will be a site on my github:  http://cammac7.github.io/
if you scroll down to the "portfolio" you'll see my issue.

Comment: So, you need your bottom row to be set of 4 triangles, smaller in size than those on the top, isn't right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Robjez I got it to work! I ended up using the below css to shift the positions of the portfolio-items in. Both rows got corrected.

```
.portfolio-item:first-child {
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
}

.portfolio-item:last-child {
    position: relative;
    left: -15%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to add 4th item then with class `col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding` with extra class ie. `leftShifted`. Apply same class to 2nd and 3rd column so you'll have `col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding leftShifted`.
Your markup will look:

```
               <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal4" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/ALS.jpg" class="tri-Up img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding leftShifted">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal5" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/kickinit.jpg" class="tri-Down img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding leftShifted">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal6" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/MarshMad.jpg" class="tri-Up img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item dontwantpadding leftShifted">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal5" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/kickinit.jpg" class="tri-Down img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Then you need to shift your 2nd, 3rd and 4th element with negative margin, like so:

```
.col-sm-4.portfolio-item.dontwantpadding.leftShifted{
   margin-left: -130px;
}
```

Obviously you need to adjust your margins between rows.
Hope this help
[image]

Comment: robjez, thanks for responding, but unfortunately, your fix didn't work for me. For some reason the negative-margin in the CSS just gets crossed out by whatever browser. I only have 6 elements now (3 on top 3 on bottom) would that affect the success of this method?

Comment: Hm. must be one of the css rules overriding it. I remember you had some !important added to one of your classes (dontwantpadding?). Can you set it up in the way I showed you (with 4 columns at the bottom), so I could have a look in web inspector? I'm sure it's specificity issue.

Comment: I did have some !important added to the dontwantpadding class, but even when I removed those I still can't get the triangles any closer. Also, I want to keep it just 3 and 3 because  I think it's cleaner that way